# obout textbox jquery autocomplete issue

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, autocomplete

I am trying to get autocomplete feature for textboxes firstname and lastname . I m using Obout Textboxes here . The problem is , autocomplete feature is not working forthe obout control but it is working fine for asp.net input type=text control .

Note that controls are in master page.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {

                    $('#<%=txtFirstName.ClientID%>').autocomplete({ source: '/Controls/AutoCompleteXHandlers/UserFirstNameXHandler.ashx', appendTo: "#firstNameContainer" });
                    $('#<%=txtLastName.ClientID%>').autocomplete({ source: '/Controls/AutoCompleteXHandlers/UserLastNameXHandler.ashx', appendTo: "#lastNameContainer" });
                });
            </script>


            <div id="titleDesc" runat="server">
                <p style="color: Red; text-align: left; font-weight: bold">
                    Please use this form to Manage the User(Contractor/Govt) Account. All questions with an '*'
                are required.Enter the FirstName and LastName for the Account you wish to manage.
                </p>
            </div>
            <br />
            <br />
            <div id="NewRegPage" class="dvNewRegParam" style="margin-left: 20px;" runat="server">
                <table id="tblManageUser" class="tblNewRegParam">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 5px 0 6px 10px;" class="td2">
                            <b>*First Name</b>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                               <obout:OboutTextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" Width="220"  >                              
                        </obout:OboutTextBox>
                        <%--    <input id="txtFirstName" type="text" runat="server" style="width: 220px" />--%>
                            <div id="firstNameContainer" style="width: auto"></div>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RFVFirstName" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtFirstName" ValidationGroup="ManageUserAccount"
                                Text="*First Name is required" CssClass="error" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```